# FlashDevelop building a project just launches Adobe CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

**UPDATE** Figured it out. Here is what happened. When I opened FlashDevelop project, then opened .fla file in CS5.  Hit build project in FlashDevelop, the output directory for the SWF was not set in CS5 publish options.  I missed that warning. Once I set the publish folder, it build fine. :-/

I"m a new to flash development.  I have inherited an existing project and trying to figure out how to compile it.

I have opened the project in [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) First time I tried to beuild it, it asked me to  specify a "`path to flash ide`", so I specified `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5` where my flash.exe lives.

Now when I build, I still don't see any output from the build and the Adobe CS5 is launched right away.  It seems that 'build project' button just launches Adobe CS5 and doesn't actually buld the project. :(

I have: FlashDevelop 4.0.1 RTM for Microsoft.NET 2.0 (R2198)

Screen shot of compiler settings:

[image]

Project Settings screen shot
[image]

Project tree

[image]

Comment: no errors. nothing in the output window or any window for that matter. it just launches Adobe CS5 :-/

Comment: Have you got the latest version of FlashDevelop installed? I had the BETA for version 4 for a while and that was giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: I have: FlashDevelop 4.0.1 RTM for Microsoft.NET 2.0 (R2198)

Answer (score 2):

i think flashDeveloper does not support flash ide cs5.5 yet, read this:

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8919

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?p=42109

Comment: I removed cs5 and installed cs3 instead. I get same behavior :(

Comment: @dev.e.loper can you provide a screenshot of project tree, do u have a fla file or not

Comment: Updated question with a screen shot of project tree. Yes I have an fla file.

Comment: @dev.e.loper open the fla file you want to compile (right click lanche) if it's opened then press f5

Comment: then press f5 in flashdevelop

Comment: Hold on. I'm in process of reverting back to CS5.  Once I'm there, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your settings window looks the same, but just in case you can notice something different:

[image]

It may also be important to ensure that you select **Flash IDE Project** from the new project window:

[image]

---

Honestly I've had a lot of trouble with this feature myself and have made a habit of just flicking over to Flash and compiling your .fla whenever necessary.. It's only an extra click in the taskbar.

P.S. I have Flash CS5.5 installed with FlashDevelop 4.0.1 RTM (same as you) and it works fine for me at the moment.

Comment: I have updated my question with screen shot of my compiler settings. Hopefully you can spot something that is not right.

Comment: @dev.e.loper Your screenshot is different - I went via `Tools` -> `Program Settings` -> `ASCompletion`.

Comment: These are *Project* settings.

Comment: @dev.e.loper Yep.. Unrelated to your problem of the project not compiling when you hit build (F5 / CTRL+ENTER) in FlasDevelop?

Comment: When I hit F5 or Ctrl+Enter, I get same behavior. Adobe CS is launched and nothing happens. No compilation errors, warning info messages no output.

Comment: @dev.e.loper Yeah, so have you mimicked the settings I have in ASCompletion as mentioned? Seems like you've only looked at Project Settings.

Comment: Yes. I updated question with screen shot of Program Settings.

Comment: @dev.e.loper No probs.. In that case I've exhausted my ideas so I'll do some reading around for you throughout the day.

Answer (score -1):

I made sure everything was inside the src folder or the project folder. I started with a Flash IDE project in Flash and in Develop I made sure to link the project files to the same folder. I turned off Create Directories.

Then, when it asked for path to flash IDE from Develop I added Adobe Flash main folder and walla when I hit F5 it opens flash, produces a swf window, and then shows me any errors from within develop instead of FLASH console.

The option in Flash Develop is Program Settings - ASCompletion - there set ADOBE FLASH.